# Why change State inside setTimeout make an infinity loop

Tags: reactjs

I have a **functional component** and I want to change State inside a `setTimeout`, but I don't know why it causes the component to be in an infinite loop!

> Here is my **Functional Component**:

```
import { useState } from "react";

function Card() {
  const [booksState, setBooks] = useState({
    books: [
      { name: "Harry", id: 1 },
      { name: "Potter", id: 2 },
      { name: "John", id: 3 },
    ],
  });

  console.log("test");

  setTimeout(() => {
    let newBooks = [
      { name: "test1", id: 4 },
      { name: "test2", id: 5 },
      { name: "test3", id: 6 },
    ];

    setBooks({
      books: [...booksState.books, ...newBooks],
    });
  }, 2000);

  return <div>TEST</div>;
}

export default Card;
```

> The **console log**:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set Timeout runs every time the component renders. This means every time the state changes, it starts a new timer. Assuming you only want to run the timer when the component first renders, you should use the `useEffect` hook as follows:

```
import { useState } from "react";

function Card() {
  const [booksState, setBooks] = useState({
    books: [
      { name: "Harry", id: 1 },
      { name: "Potter", id: 2 },
      { name: "John", id: 3 },
    ],
  });

  console.log("test");

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let newBooks = [
        { name: "test1", id: 4 },
        { name: "test2", id: 5 },
        { name: "test3", id: 6 },
      ];

      setBooks({
        books: [...booksState.books, ...newBooks],
      });
    }, 2000)
  }, []);

  return <div>TEST</div>;
}

export default Card;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `setTimeout` inside a `useEffect` to avoid infinite calling of `setTimeout`.

In the current implementation, setTimeout gets called again after the first timeout completes (due to rerendering) which causes it to exponentially accumulate the timeout calls.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let newBooks = [
        { name: "test1", id: 4 },
        { name: "test2", id: 5 },
        { name: "test3", id: 6 }
      ];

      setBooks({
        books: [...booksState.books, ...newBooks]
      });
    }, 2000);
  }, []);
```

[image: Edit serene-mclean-pirz2i]

Answer (score 1):

In your current implementation `setTimeout` runs every time the component renders means on every state update so because of that it's getting called again and again. So, you need to call `setTimeout` inside of `useEffect`. **And don't forget to `clearTimeout` in the `useEffect`'s cleanup function.**

```
useEffect(() => {
   const myTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      let newBooks = [
        { name: "test1", id: 4 },
        { name: "test2", id: 5 },
        { name: "test3", id: 6 },
      ];

      setBooks({
        books: [...booksState.books, ...newBooks],
      });
    }, 2000)
  
   return () => {
     clearTimeout(myTimeout)
   }

  }, []);
```